# Swift: Double Buffering like in Java

Tags: java, swift, animation, view, graphics

In Java, I can write pixel data to an image that is then printed to the screen by overridden methods (paint and paintComponent). I can refresh the screen easily by updating the image and calling refresh(), which calls the paint/paintComponent cycle.

I'm wanting to do this in swift (3) with a UIImage. I can update the image, but I can't figure out how to repeatedly project the image onto the screen, print the screen, and repeat as I need to refresh the screen.

Firstly, what type of swift project (Single view app., Game, etc.) is best for repeatedly refreshing the screen?

And secondly how do I go about creating a (regulated) loop in Swift that refreshes the screen every so often?

In java this would look like (in a class that extends Frame):

```
static int width = 1440;
static int height = 900;

private BufferedImage canvas;
static Color[][] RGBMap = new Color[width][height];

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g2.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    g2.drawImage(this.canvas, null, null);

    paint();
}

public void paint() {

    int i = 0;
    while (i < width) {
        int t = 0;
        while (t < height) {
            this.canvas.setRGB(i, t, RGBMap[i][t].getRGB());
            t++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    //Refreshes RGBMap
    iterate();

    repaint();
}
```